# Why won't my site column deploy from an elements file?

Tags: visual-studio, feature, site-column, elements-xml

See [Can site columns be deployed in sandboxed solutions?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22876/can-site-columns-be-deployed-in-sandboxed-solutions) for background on this.

I've tried to reproduce the sandboxed feature with a site column as built by Hilton Giesenow shown on [How Do I: Create a Site Column in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ff536010).  When I used a content type project like he did, it worked as he shows.  However, if I start with an empty sharepoint project and add an empty element file (which creates a feature much like he shows in his video), it doesn't work.

I opened up the resulting WSPs and compared the XML.  What I found was that the packages were identical with the exception of the GloballyAvailable property set to "True" on the feature built in the content type project like Giesenow did.  I added that property to my feature, rebuilt the packages, and compared the resulting XML and found no differences other than feature names/IDs.  I redacted some of the naming to keep a client anonymous.

[image: Comparison of WSP files]

Now what?  Why does one work and not the other?

I found [an article that made me think that ensuring the name of the empty element matched the `Field` element's name attribute would do the trick](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23024/why-wont-my-site-column-deploy-from-an-elements-file):

> The Name attribute of the WebTemplate element will have to exactly the
>   same as the name of your Empty Element in Visual Studio. If these two
>   don’t match the web template won’t deploy properly.

I renamed the element node in my project to "OrderIndex" to match the name of my site column, and that didn't work either.

Update: after doing some more looking, I found [Walkthrough: Create a Custom Field, Content Type, List Definition, and List Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231593.aspx) on MSDN.  I pretty much followed exactly the directions in the "Custom Field" section.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: No error.  The column just doesn't appear in the Site Column Gallery.

Comment: Check the ULS logs for the moments after you activate the Feature, there should be some clues there.

Comment: Alright.  I found this: `Solution Deployment : Missing one or more of the following attributes from the root node in solution XXXXXXX.wsp: assembly '', type ''.`  According to the internets this is an ambiguous message that means roughly something like "your sandboxed solution contains unsupported somethings-or-other".  One person had restricted code, and another suggested it might be unsupported attributes in the `Field` element.  Not sure what they would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer, which is summed up neatly by Phil Harding in [SharePoint Integer and Numeric Field (Site Column) Types](http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/sharepoint-integer-and-numeric-field-site-column-types/).

Bottom line: it was working all along, just not visible in the Site Column Gallery (which means it could only be used in content types, not in UI-built custom lists).  If you want it to show up in the gallery, you have to use a type marked with `UserCreatable = TRUE`.

My column still isn't in the Gallery, but here's what PowerShell has to say about it:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $site.RootWeb.Fields |? {$_.Group -eq "XXXX"} | ft InternalName,Type

InternalName                 Type
------------                 ----
OrderIndex                   Integer
```